# OS X mavericks update issue

Tags: macos, imac, xcode

am trying to update my iMac 21.5 inch mid 2010 from os x mavericks 10.9.1 to 10.9.5 to work on Xcode 6 but it always fail and give me the alert message OS X Update could not be verified . It may have been corrupted or tampered with during downloading . Click download and check the update again

can anybody help

Comment: Where did you download the upgrade from?

Comment: I am connected to my wifi network and i am trying the update from the apple store

Answer (score 1):

If you're running antivirus software, you may wish to try disabling it and downloading your updates from the App Store again. If that doesn't work, try downloading the combo update from here:

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1760

You may find that this works where downloading from the App Store fails.

Comment: Also the same result ! it maybe connection problem ? really I am confused :/

Comment: Or it maybe because the version of this iMac it seems somehow old so its not supported with new updates ?

Comment: This could be a connection problem. If you can use an Ethernet connection, that may improve the situation for you.